# In a Scrapy bot, how do I call one function from within another?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I know this is a newbie question, and it's a basic Python question, but it's within the context of Scrapy and I can't find the answer anywhere.

When I run this bot code:

```
import scrapy

from tutorial.items import DmozItem

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["lib-web.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.lib-web.org/united-states/public-libraries/michigan/"
    ]

    count = 0

    def increment(self):
        global count
        count += 1

    def getCount(self):
        global count
        return count

    def parse(self, response):
        increment()
        for sel in response.xpath('//div/div/div/ul/li'):
            item = DmozItem()
            item['title'] = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            item['link'] = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            item['desc'] = sel.xpath('p/text()').extract()
            x = getCount()
            print x
            yield item
```

DmozItem:

```
import scrapy

class DmozItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    desc = scrapy.Field()
```

I get this error:

```
File "/Users/Admin/scpy_projs/tutorial/tutorial/spiders/dmoz_spider.py", line 23, in parse
    increment()
NameError: global name 'increment' is not defined
```

Why I can't call `increment()` from within `parse(self, response)`? How can I make this work?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`increment()` is an *instance method* of your spider - use `self.increment()` to call it.

Also, there is no need for using globals - define `count()` as an instance variable.

Fixed version:

```
import scrapy

from tutorial.items import DmozItem

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["lib-web.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.lib-web.org/united-states/public-libraries/michigan/"
    ]

    def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        super(DmozSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.count = 0

    def increment(self):
        self.count += 1

    def getCount(self):
        return self.count

    def parse(self, response):
        self.increment()

        for sel in response.xpath('//div/div/div/ul/li'):
            item = DmozItem()
            item['title'] = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            item['link'] = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            item['desc'] = sel.xpath('p/text()').extract()
            x = self.getCount()
            print x

            yield item
```

You can also [define `count` as a property.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work)

Comment: I gotta read up on __init__ and self. Thanks for the direction. It's what I needed.